# C# - Set excel cell with a formula containing double quotes

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, double-quotes

I'm trying to set via c# code the formula of an excel cell.
I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, version 14.
I always get an excel error 0x800A03EC, which is a kind of generic error.

```
String formula = "=IF(A2=\"BLANCO\";\"\";C1+1)"    

Range cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ws.Cells[2, 3];
cell.Formula = formula;
```

I also tried to escape the double quotes with an @

```
String formula = @"=IF(A2=""BLANCO"";"""";C1+1)"
```

Same error, same problem.

When I try to set a simple formula, where no quotes are involved it is working fine.

Anybody has a solution?

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be `@"=IF(A2=""BLANCO"","""",C1+1)"` (commas not semicolons)?

Comment: D Stanley is right, use commas in the formula not ;

Comment: this solution solved the problem for my code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951868/649825

Answer (score 2):

Don't have much context for your code, but slashes should work when used appropriately. I am not sure about the use of semicolons here.

This code is an example pulled straight from one of my Interop programs and works fine:
`thisExcel.xlWorksheet.Range["AD44", Type.Missing].Value = "=IF(BULK!L7=\"#N/A Field Not Applicable\",\"( \"&'Title Look Up'!C3&\" )\",\"( \"&'Title Look Up'!C3&\" )\")";`

If all you want is: 'if a2 reads blanco then nothing else increment value of c1 by 1', then you just need:
`=IF(A2=\"BLANCO\",\"\",C1+1)`

I would also try using .Value rather than .Formula.

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @getglad's answer - Using a slash does work for double quotes.

My recent solution (as of 2020):

```
worksheet.Cells[row,col].Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(etc),\"\")";
```